# Brick texture to a part of a mesh

Tags: texturing

I am new to blender and for a university project i need to make a brick texture for a part of the mesh like in the image just for the castle. I tried by adding a texture to some faces in edit mode but because they have different shapes the texture goes all wrong. anyone have an idea? [image: click here for the image]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). To make the brick texture look correct, you need to UV unwrap your model. If you've never done it before, here is a [useful tutorial from BlenderGuru](https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k).

Comment: You also should use the ***Smart UV project***, and adjust the textures on the faces in the image editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all the faces you want to assign the texture. Press 'U' and click in 'Unwrap'. If the texture is already assigned to those faces it will automatically distribute the texture. If not you can go in 'Material Properties' in the right side of the screen and click 'assign' with the texture you want selected.

If you want your bricks to be smaller you can create a texture map in your node ang set the scale of the texture higher. This will make the material look smaller in the mesh but will also show its rectangular pattern if it gets too small.

Best regards.

[image]